# Input attribute doesn't update when const change value

Tags: reactjs

The value of `pickedTrue` changes from false to true as the component is mounting. but the input `defaultChecked` doesn't update it just sets as false.

page.js:

```
function page() {
    return (
        <Checkbox checked={'1'} />
    )
}

export default page
```

checkbox component:

```
function Checkbox({checked}) {
 const pickedTrue = checked == '1' ? true : false

 console.log(pickedTrue)

 return (
     <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={pickedTrue}/>
  )
 }

export default Checkbox
```

`console.log(pickedTrue)` output:

```
undefined

false

undefined

undefined

true
```

*note: if i use `===` instead of `==` it results in `false` either way.

Comment: may be you should replace the `defaultChecked` to `checked` like this: ` <input type="checkbox" checked={pickedTrue}/>`,try it

Comment: maybe `<input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={checked === '1'}/>`?

Comment: @screwspike i tried that at first. but then it become read-only. it even shows a warning saying i sohould use `defaultChecked`

Comment: @Daniel. the value `checked '1'` is coming from a database and the component  is used in other pages. and not all value is `1`. thats why i made it conditonal: `const pickedTrue = checked == '1' ? true : false`

Answer (score 2):

You can handle it with useState. Because the state rerender every change.

```
  ...

  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  console.log(checked);

  return (
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}
      defaultChecked={checked}
    />
  );
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-n1xmc)

Comment: thank you for the answer. but it still doesnt work. the input doesnt update when value changes.

Comment: Can you check the my demo link?

Answer (score 2):

Use a state variable instead of a constant value. To effectively log changes to your variable you can best use useEffect with a dependency. In your dependency use checked instead of defaultChecked and add an onChange-function so your input will update when you click on the checkbox.

```
function Checkbox({defaultChecked}) {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(defaultChecked === '1');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(checked);
  }, [checked])

  return (
    <input type="checkbox" 
      checked={checked} 
      onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: useState(defaultChecked === '1')? does this mean that assumption if 'defaultChecked ' is true, then ( true === '1') is true?! because 'true' is boolean and '1' is string!

Comment: OP said in the comments that this value is coming from a database. I assumed from his code that this value is stored and / or retrieved as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone else suggested, you might wanna keep track of values in a local state.

Anyway, here's my take on your problem.
It can accept 0 and 1 and sets the checkboxes accordingly.

CodeSandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-lovelace-41y75?file=/src/Checkbox.jsx

Ref - https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-checkbox/

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reassign the value of constant which cannot be done. as the value once assigned cannot be changed. And like most of the answers, you should use the state to store the value even when it is coming from the database. You can create a separate function and call it for the `defaultChecked`. You can do something like this -

```
function Checkbox({checked}) {
 const [checkedValue, setCheckedValue] = useState(checked === 1 ? true : false)

const setChecked = () => {
  setChecked(!checked)
}

 return (
     <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={checkedValue} onClick={setChecked}/>
  )
 }

export default Checkbox
```

Always try using the `===` strict equality operator which sure the answer isn't anything else but the one with which its type is matched against. When you used the strict equality operator it returned false because you sent a string `1` as a prop and were checking it against the integer 1.